# How to pass variable information from one class to another in Python

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, global-variables, parameter-passing

I'm really struggling on how I can pass variable information from one class to another in Python.  I have a program that I am creating that detects the file type based on the extension or file name.  I originally set the file name to whatever the args are (hard coded for now but will use argparse).  If I detect a zip file then I will extract the zip and pull the test.xml out and reassign that file path to the variable.  However, when I call it from another class, I get the old path (that was assigned from args).  I'm new to Python and this is kicking my butt.  Hopefully someone can help me here.  Here is an example of my code:

Main class:

```
class ValidateTest(Parameterize.ParametrizedTestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='' + '')
        parser.add_argument('-d', '--driver', help='Path and file name of xml or zip driver file', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity',
                            help='Verbosity for test output.  1 for terse, 2 for verbose.  Default is verbose',
                            default=1, type=int)
        args = "c:\\test.zip"
        self.filename = args
        #self.verbosity = args.verbosity

    def main(self):
        # Test for a valid xml file.  This could be a .xml, .zip, or test.xml
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.filename))[1] == '.xml':
            self.assertTrue(True, logger.passed("A file with a valid extension of '.xml' was detected."))
        elif os.path.basename(self.filename) == 'test.xml':
            self.assertTrue(True, logger.passed("A file with the valid name of 'test.xml' was detected."))
        elif os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.filename))[1] == '.zip':
            self.assertTrue(True, logger.passed("A file with the valid extension of '.zip' was detected."))

            # Test if the .zip is a valid zip file
            if zipfile.is_zipfile(self.filename):
                self.assertTrue(True, logger.passed("%s is a valid zip file" % self.filename))
                self.assertTrue(True, logger.info("Extracting .zip to obtain test.xml."))

                # Extract the .zip and pull out the test.xml.
                tempDirectory = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix="", prefix="TEST_")
                with zipfile.ZipFile(self.filename) as zf:
                    zf.extractall(tempDirectory)
                    self.filename = tempDirectory + os.path.sep + "test.xml"
            else:
                self.assertTrue(False, logger.failed("%s is not a valid zip file" % self.filename))
        else:
            self.assertTrue(False, logger.failed("Invalid file detected.  A valid file has a .xml or .zip extension.  Extension must be lower-case.  test.xml is also a valid file"))
        # TODO: Remove the temp directory after complete.
        return validate.run(self.filename) == False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    validateTest = ValidateTest()
    sys.exit(validateTest.main())
```

As you can see in the **init** function I assign self.filename the value of the args variable.  Later on in the main function I detect a zip file and then set self.filename = the new file path and name.  However, as you will see below, I am calling this self.filename variable from another class and I get the original value that was assigned from args.  See below:

```
class Tests(Parameterize.ParametrizedTestCase):
    def test_validateIrCode(self, ircode):
        driver = ElementTree.parse(Main.ValidateTest().filename)
```

The value of filename is c:\test.zip instead of the extracted file... like, c:\temp\test.xml

If any of you could provide some clear examples, I would be greatful.  I've tried using global variables and passing the variable as a parameter but I am obviously doing something wrong as I get syntax errors or the same results.

Comment: Don't you need an argument for your second to last line of code (`ValidateTest()`)?

Comment: It runs without it.  What argument are you suggesting I pass?  have an example?